# I can't change the fill color of a SVG Sprite

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpyMxV) where I have made an example of the SVG Sprites Technique:

And I want to apply this with CSS:

```css
.circle {
    fill: #f00;
}
.polyline {
    fill: #00f;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"style="position:absolute;top:-9999px;opacity:0;">    
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 64 64" id="circle">
            <title>circle</title>
                <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M32,0C14.327,0,0,14.327,0,32c0,17.673,14.327,32,32,32s32-14.327,32-32C64,14.327,49.673,0,32,0z M32,52.5c-11.322,0-20.5-9.178-20.5-20.5S20.678,11.5,32,11.5S52.5,20.678,52.5,32S43.322,52.5,32,52.5z"/>
        </symbol>
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 56.983 64.804" id="polyline">
            <title>polyline</title>
                <polyline fill="#1D1D1B" points="0,64.804 30.726,0 56.983,0 56.983,54.749 29.33,27.095 "/>
        </symbol>
    </svg>

    <svg class="circle">
        <use xlink:href="#circle"></use>
    </svg>

    <svg class="polyline">
        <use xlink:href="#polyline"></use>
    </svg>
```

My problem is that I'm not able to change the fill color of the elements added to the spritesheet. I have looked for information about how to do this correctly and I think my approach it's correct but it seems that it's not like that.

In this other [pen](http://codepen.io/team/lincolnloop/details/GgdLBa), wrote in the same way I think, is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for my english if I have made any mistake, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to remove internal styling of fill property and only apply css property. Either way change fill property of svg using javascript DOM.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqmrOR

The problem was the `fill="#1D1D1B"` attributes placed directly on the SVG elements.

**NOTE**: Using CSS class selectors on SVG elements, while supported in most up-to-date browsers, is not universally supported. Programmatically applying styles to SVG elements in JS themselves is actually better supported.

Comment: Thank you! I will consider to add a fallback with JS.

Answer (score 5):

When using the command `<use xlink: href =" # circle "> </use>` the content of the SVG element goes to the `Shadow DOM`
Therefore, it becomes impossible to change styles with external CSS
The solution to this problem is to use forced ʻinherit` inheritance

```
 polyline, path {
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
```

You can read more in this article: [Styling SVG  Content with CSS](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/)

```css
polyline, path {
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
 .circle {
fill:yellowgreen;
} 
 .circle:hover {
fill:red;
} 

.polyline {
fill:gold;
}

.polyline:hover {
fill:red;
}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"style="position:absolute;top:-9999px;opacity:0;">    
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 64 64" id="circle">
        <title>circle</title>
            <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M32,0C14.327,0,0,14.327,0,32c0,17.673,14.327,32,32,32s32-14.327,32-32C64,14.327,49.673,0,32,0z M32,52.5c-11.322,0-20.5-9.178-20.5-20.5S20.678,11.5,32,11.5S52.5,20.678,52.5,32S43.322,52.5,32,52.5z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 56.983 64.804" id="polyline">
        <title>polyline</title>
            <polyline fill="#1D1D1B" points="0,64.804 30.726,0 56.983,0 56.983,54.749 29.33,27.095 "/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="circle">
    <use  xlink:href="#circle"></use>
</svg>

<svg class="polyline">
    <use  xlink:href="#polyline" ></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok, how to set 3 difference colors for svg with 3 paths inside?

Comment: @a.yushko For three paths Just like for two

Comment: Ok! It works nicely in Firefox, but doesn't work in webkit based browsers. Chrome, Opera, Edge can't override shadow-root properties of SVG's in sprite.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I like is the css `filter` property.

Based on [How to transform black into any given color using only CSS filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters) you can adjust the filter to change the svg's color to whatever you want.
More info: https://medium.com/@union_io/swapping-fill-color-on-image-tag-svgs-using-css-filters-fa4818bf7ec6

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has CSS styling problems with SVG icons. Here how it goes:

```
<svg width="28" height="26" viewBox="0 0 28 26" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M27.333..../>
</svg>
```

Styling is applied on inner ***path*** element and not to the **svg** directly.
The correct styling:

```
svg path {
   fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to remove internal styling inside svg file (as sprite.svg) like thisnthen add styles inside normal CSS file

```
<g fill="rgb(0,0,0)">
```

//delete fill = "rgb(0,0,0)" , then add your style in css file

```
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference a class add onto the svg tag and target the path and change the colour in the css file.

example

```
    .logoSvg path {
  fill: var(--green-text-colour);
}
```

to reach all svgs at once

```
    svg path {
  fill: var(--green-text-colour);
}
```