# Change color of SVG sprite

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using SVG sprite as my background image:

```
.naar-logo {
    background: url(images/salt_sprite.svg) no-repeat -8px -78px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 49px;
    position: relative;
    top: 38px;
}
<div class="naar-logo"></div>
```

Color of sprite images is black, but I want it to be white. I tried with:

`background: url(images/salt_sprite.svg) no-repeat white -8px -78px;`

and `color: white;` on `.naar-logo` clas, but it not work. How can I change color of svg sprite to be white?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't change the fill color of a SVG Sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971550/i-cant-change-the-fill-color-of-a-svg-sprite)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the color with an external css. You need to inline the SVG in order to to that. Please read [Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) for details.